# raspberry pi server not loading codeigniter images

Tags: apache, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to make a simple site with codeigniter in a raspberry pi, in my PC works perfect (hosted with xampp) but when I upload it to the raspberry it's not loading the images.

the files are at /var/www/jobform and the config at at sites-available is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerAdmin master@server.com 
    ServerName www.consiguetrabajo.ddns.net 
    ServerAlias consiguetrabajo.ddns.net 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/jobform/
</VirtualHost>
```

The code above also appears linked with the sites-enabled

the weird thing is that when I access the site within the raspberry, the images wont load unless I go to them directly (like consiguetrabajo.ddns.net/assets/imgs/img.png)

when I try to access the images from outsite (another pc) it takes a lot of time to respond and then it fails to load. in fact, if you enter now, it displays an error like if you are entering already posting a request.

https://prnt.sc/odm4re

here is also a picture of the directorys

https://prntscr.com/odm88a

also, in the logs at /var/log/apache2 there are no erros displaying, so I'm lost, I'm not sure what else I can do

Comment: is your `base_url` correctly set in your `config.php`? Can check the rendered page source code in your browser and see what exactly is on the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag?

Comment: Yes, it is correctly pointing at the domain and image. In fact. If you try to open it from an outside computer it takes a long time to load and it doesn't list at the end. It only loads when you access it from the raspberry pi. And only if you try to access it directly